# Can a windows Print Processor force a spool data type

Tags: c++, windows, printing, driver, wdk

I'm developing a Windows Print Processor using the WDK 7.1 sample. I'd like to log the actual data being printed and would prefer it to be done in a consistent format (EMF) rather than the RAW format of the underlying printer. Would modifying `EnumPrintProcessorDatatypes` to only return the format I want (i.e EMF) force application/GDI layer the printer to use that type and thereby enabling me to log it in the same format always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important stuff here is:
 1. make sure direct printing is disabled
 2. make sure advanced printing is enabled

If the driver is XPS based, the job will go thru the `XPSPRINT` pipeline, and never be formated as EMF.

You can find more informataion on when EMF or RAW is used on the following Undocumented Printing page:
http://www.undocprint.org/winspool/spool_files#when_is_raw_used