# How exactly does the windows spooler decide what data type it's going to send to the print processor?

Tags: c++, c, windows, printing, wdk

For example if you want to be spooling in EMF, usually what works is ticking "Advanced printing features". However, I've noticed that on some printer drivers this does not work (which is not unexpected, it's not mandatory for v3 drivers to support it). Indeed, I've noticed on one driver that a device-dependent setting (i.e. in the extra end chunk of the DEVMODE structure) was what determined whether the spool file came out in EMF. So how does the print spooler determine which datatype to pass down?

I've looked through the print driver DDI functions and structures and can't find anything pertaining to this. In `DrvDeviceCapabilities` there is a `DC_EMF_COMPLIANT` flag, however that is only for Windows 95. How does the spooler do it on later systems?

Comment: Looks like this question has been left to go dusty :( Similar question was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932044/can-a-windows-print-processor-force-a-spool-data-type?rq=1 but answer just said to set the spool properties, which can't be correct as I've observed it to depend on the device-independent settings.

Comment: *device-dependent I meant to say, not independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I have found a sufficient (but perhaps not necessary) condition for the driver to force the spooler to use RAW. If `DrvEscape` is called querying support for `METAFILE_DRIVER` and the driver returns 0, then the spooler will spool straight to raw no matter what. This is the case for the driver I had found that does this.